# django-oauth-toolkit to issue a JWT token

Tags: django, django-oauth

Tech Stack Django1.10.8 + Python3.6 + docker + React + Axios.js

I have a situation where I need to make a server to server call and for this I am using Django-OAuth-toolkit. How can I convert this token to issue JWT token instead?

{
    "access_token": "txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFB45a",
    "expires_in": 36000,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "read write groups",
    "refresh_token": "16oKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

to

{
    "access_token": "xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx",
    "expires_in": 36000,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "read write groups",
    "refresh_token": "xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx"
}

I have gone through https://github.com/Humanitec/django-oauth-toolkit-jwt/
but I think the version I am using of django-oauth-toolkit are incompatible.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by subclassing the `oauthlib.oauth2.Server`

```
class OauthServer(oauth2.Server):
    def __init__(self, request_validator, token_expires_in=None, token_generator=None, *args, **kwargs):
        token_generator = custom_token_generator
        super().__init__(request_validator, token_expires_in, token_generator, *args, **kwargs)
```

The `custom_token_generator` function will generate the jwt token

```
def custom_token_generator(request, refresh_token=False):
    client_code = request.user and request.user.client.codigo

    now = datetime.now()
    payload = {
        'iat': int(now.timestamp()),
        'exp': int(expires.timestamp()),
    }
    if client_code:
        payload['org'] = client_code
    return jwt.encode(payload, settings.JWT['EC_PRIVATE_KEY'].encode(), algorithm='ES256').decode('ascii')
```

It's not the ideal JWT, but you can make what you need, the only problem is changing the AccessToken and RefreshToken `token` field to a TextField since the JWT length will go way over the limit

```
from oauth2_provider.models import AbstractAccessToken, AbstractRefreshToken

class AccessToken(AbstractAccessToken):
    token = models.TextField()

class RefreshToken(AbstractRefreshToken):
    token = models.TextField()
```

the [django-oauth-toolkit docs](http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html) will have more information on overwriting these fields on the django settings

Comment: Can you explain what is the role of class OauthServer
Where should this be registered?
I am facing the same issue.

Comment: It would be great if you can point to the necessary changes in settings.py as well